# Error in All sample times for this block must be discrete. No continuous or constant sample times are allowed

Tags: matlab, simulink, dsss

I'm designing DSS System, the problems is when I execute it this error occurs:

```
Error in 'DSS_System_withANFIS/Synchronization Unit/Acquisition/Integrate and Dump1': All sample times for this block must be discrete. No continuous or constant sample times are allowed.
```

Here is my overall system design:
[image: DSS System]

and this is my acquisition subsystem of Synchronization unit:
[image: Acquisition Unit]

The error occurred at integrate and dump unit.
Any help?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution.

I just changed the solver to discrete in configuration parameters in simulink UI

[image]